# Retrieve all data in collection in new MongoDB-C driver

Tags: mongodb, bson, mongodb-c

I have a very simple question in appearance but for which I've been stuck for several days.

What method would you consider (the most effective one, if you know several) to retrieve all the data present in a collection ?

Here's the structure of my collection example :

```
collection = {
   _id: ObjectId(""),
   field: ""
}
```

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To construct a query in mongodb-c driver,

```
  bson_init( query );
  bson_finish( query );
```

// if you want to add more search parameters then in between those two add

```
  bson_append_int( query, "age", 24 );
```

You can keep adding more search criteria.

Here is one example:

```
  bson query[1];
  mongo_cursor cursor[1];

  bson_init( query );
  bson_append_int( query_buf, "age", 24 ); // to match particular criteria, remove this line to match call documents
  bson_finish( query );

  mongo_cursor_init( cursor, conn, "test.collection" );
  mongo_cursor_set_query( cursor, query )

  while( mongo_cursor_next( cursor ) == MONGO_OK ) {
    bson_iterator iterator[1];
    if ( bson_find( iterator, mongo_cursor_bson( cursor ), "name" )) {
        printf( "name: %s\n", bson_iterator_string( it ) );
    }
  }

  bson_destroy( query );
  mongo_cursor_destroy( cursor );
```

This is equivalent to:

```
db.collection.find()
```